# How to generate a core controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have deleted the main controller Laravel by path: `App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php;`

All new controllers extent this controller:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
}
```

How to generate a core controller in Laravel again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't regenerate core Controller class via command neither `artisan` nor `composer` . You have to copy this from github or another project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either you are able to regenerate it. But you can get a copy of the content [here](http://pastebin.com/QwsdHGZC)